# Using an assignment operator with make_pair method generates a CLion warning

Tags: c++, clion

In my program there is an array of pairs declared as it follows:

```
pair <string, int> mostOftenPairs[10];
```

When I want to, for example, initialise it:

```
for (short i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    mostOftenPairs[i] = make_pair(std::string(), 0);
```

CLion underscores a line where an assignment occurs and when I hover on it, I get this error:

```
'pair::operator=(type)' is deleted
```

However, the program runs without any problems but my question is if there is any method used for assigning values to pairs instead of '='? Is it possible to initialise the array of pairs in the same line? I mean something similar to this one:

```
pair <string, int> mostOftenPairs[10] = make_pair(std::string(), 0);
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question body as well, and mark out where in the code the error is.

Comment: @user463035818 that is the full warning that I get. I mean CLion underscores a line where an assignment occurs and when I hover on it, that is the warning I get.

Comment: @FredLarson yes, I wrongly described the origin of the error.

Comment: I hope so, I've already added a CLion tag 5 minutes ago. I am curious if the error occurs in any other IDE because, at least for me, this error suggests that there is another method instead of assignment operator. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to initialise the array of pairs in the same line? I mean something similar to this one:

To default initialize them you do not need to do anything, as stated in documentation for `std::pair` [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)

> 1) Default constructor. **Value-initializes both elements of the pair**, first and second.

(emphasis is mine) so default constructor of `std::pair` will initialize  already (empty string and 0 for int), if you need not default value use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> mostOftenPairs( 10, std::make_pair( std::string(), 1 ) );
```